# distriqt gameservices distriqtApplicationKey

Tags: android

Thanks for the KickStarter Game Services ANE.

Where can I grab a distriqtApplicationKey to test the ANE with? The extension is not yet listed on the subscription (http://airnativeextensions.com/user/646/subscriptions)  page so i can't subscribe to it and grab a key.

The test APK (just using the ANE and example .as files) so far is 34mb, so I'm assuming after AIR runtime the ANE storage is about 20mb?- is the final version likely to be this big or can it be reduced somewhat?

Thanks

Marcus

Answer (score 0):

If you were a kickstarter backer then you won't need an Application Key for the extension. You should be able to pass an empty string into the version we supplied.

We are looking to add it to our site this week.

Regarding the size, the frameworks are quite large however we are looking to provide a couple of versions of it to reduce loads when they aren't required.

Love to hear how you go!

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Michael, Wil do :)